# How return details of updated row?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have database in MS Access 2016, and want to run update query thru Excel VBA - this works. After this I want to return details of updated row (values from two columns  - ID, Col1). Now I have only number of affected rows. How to achive this?

My query:

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT TOP 1 ID, Col1, Update_time, Update_user 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Update_user Is Null 
ORDER BY Col2 DESC , ID)  AS U_ROW 
SET U_ROW.Update_time = Now(), U_ROW.Update_user = [username];
```

In Excel VBA I run it thru ADODB.Command:

```
    With baseRecordsetCommand
        .ActiveConnection = objectConnection
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "qryTest"
        .NamedParameters = True
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@username", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, LCase(Environ("Username")))
        .Execute recordsAffected
    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually these kind of ops goes into a stored procedure but in Ms Acces/Excel you have to use VBA. Easiest way is, to retrieve the Id you are about to update before you the update.

So this comes first: save it in a variable

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID
FROM Table1 
WHERE Update_user Is Null 
ORDER BY Col2 DESC , ID
```

And then

```
update Table1
SET Table1.Update_time = Now(), Table1.Update_user = @username where Id = @idFromFirstQuery;
```

followed by

```
select * from Table1 where Id = @idFromFirstQuery;
```

in this way you know what Id, row you are updating.

**OR:**

you can turn the `now()` also into a parameter and supply a timestamp as parameter.
like:

`update (table selection )
set update_time = '2020-19-03 10:0=10:10', update_user = 'User1';`

after update you can do something like:
`Select * 
from Table1 
where update_user = 'User1' and update_time = '2020-19-03 10:0=10:10';`

**NOTE!!** you are highly assuming the timestamp you are supplying + username is unique. I personally would not use this method.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure on this, but if you have a unique id, you could do something like this.  This was done in Access, so the connection would need to be set up, as i believe this is ok.

```
Function sqlret() As String

Dim c As ADODB.Connection
Dim s As String
Dim r As ADODB.Recordset
Dim l As Long

Set c = CurrentProject.Connection

c.Execute "insert into tblprojects(projecttitle) values ('code1')"
Set r = New ADODB.Recordset
r.Open "select @@identity", c, 1
l = r.Fields(0).Value
r.Close

r.Open "select * from tblprojects where [projectid]=" & l, c, 1
sqlret = r.GetString

End Function
```